# Hide/Disable TitleBar Mozilla FireFox using Javascript

Tags: javascript

How to disable the Minimize button of FireFox Browser or How to hide titlebar of FireFox Browser. I am using Window.Open to Open Window in fullscreen Mode using javascript

Answer (score 4):

I am afraid this is impossible to do, and rightly so. I would be pretty annoyed if a webpage tried disable the minimize button of my browser.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it seems to be possible to specify these features. An excerpt from [window.open Reference](http://javascript.about.com/library/blpopup10.htm):

- **dialog** can be set to yes or no to indicate whether or not the maximize and minimize buttons will display in the titlebar in Firefox, Mozilla, and Netscape only.
- **minimizable** can be set to yes or no to indicate whether or not the minimize buttons will display in the titlebar when dialog=yes in Firefox, Mozilla, and Netscape only.
  So, just use code like this:

  var newWin = window.open('http://www.google.com/','google','dialog=yes,minimizable=no');

Anyway, don't overuse this feature – it's designed explicitly with dialogs in mind. IMO, combining it with full-screen is kinda dirty.

Answer (score 1):

Try This one
http://www.ghacks.net/2008/11/19/setup-firefox-to-use-minimal-screen-estate/
It will help you to hide title bar

Answer (score 0):

try the experimental add-on "Hide Caption"